# SQL select from union only returns the first match

Tags: sql, select, union

I want to get the unique values from two small lists and use the result to select those from a big list. However, only the first result is returned. What am I doing wrong?

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.keys, b.names
FROM biglist b
WHERE
b.keys = (SELECT keys FROM partial_list_1 UNION SELECT keys FROM partial_list_2)
```

Query with a normal list for testing, this works as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.keys, b.names
FROM biglist b, smalllist s
WHERE
b.keys = s.keys
```

**//EDIT**: I'm using SpatiaLite.

Comment: What database are you using?  The `=` should return in error in any database when the subquery has more than on erow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally much more efficient to represent this as two different operations using `or`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.keys, b.names
FROM biglist b
WHERE b.keys IN (SELECT keys FROM partial_list_1) OR
      b.keys IN (SELECT keys FROM partial_list_2);
```

These can take advantage of indexes on `partial_list_1(keys)` and `partial_list_2(keys)` -- both of which are recommended.  (Some databases might need this expressed as `exists` to take advantage of the index.)

Comment: How does that compare to the join-based approach I suggested?  Am I wrong to think that an inner join is often a better choice than `WHERE x IN (subquery)`?  Or at least no worse?

Comment: I know using `WHERE EXISTS ... OR EXISTS` in Oracle is generally awful. YMMV.

Comment: @JohnBollinger . . . An inner join can be much, much, much worse if you have duplicate key values that result is a large intermediate result set.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.keys, b.names
FROM biglist b
WHERE
b.keys IN (SELECT keys FROM partial_list_1 UNION SELECT keys FROM partial_list_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This condition:

```
b.keys = (SELECT keys FROM partial_list_1 UNION SELECT keys FROM partial_list_2)
```

requires the subquery to produce a single value.  If it doesn't then the query is invalid.  Your particular DBMS may handle that by choosing one element returned by the subquery when there is more than one, but it could instead throw an error.

This would do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.keys, b.names
FROM
  biglist b
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT keys FROM partial_list_1
    UNION
    SELECT keys FROM partial_list_2
  ) s 
    ON b.keys = s.keys
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Change your equality operator to `IN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.keys, b.names
FROM biglist b
WHERE
b.keys IN (SELECT keys FROM partial_list_1 UNION SELECT keys FROM partial_list_2)
```

Or you could use `EXISTS`, which might run faster

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.keys, b.names
FROM biglist b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM partial_list_1 t1 WHERE t1.keys = b.keys)
OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM partial_list_2 t1 WHERE t1.keys = b.keys)
```